# time difference between counting lines in a file from python/unix

Tags: python, unix, time, wc

im using 'wc -l' for file with 50 columns and 3000 records to count the lines in python code itself below

```
cmd='wc -l /path of file'

status,output=command.getstatusoutput(cmd)
```

and again i tried using the below one in python

```
row_count=sum(1 for line in(file path))
```

I just tried taking time from both of the commands wc -l is faster,I just dont know which is faster could you let me know the reasons behind this

ex : time

```
wc -l : 0.005s
python : 0.54s
```

Comment: I guess wc util is written in c but your solution in python which takes more time to evaluate. Don't forget that python is interpreted language.

Comment: @funnydman any detail explanation would be helpful ,as I'm learning the difference in these two ,so I can contrast about python

Comment: this is too broad. I need to write a book to explain it. Start from understanding differences between compilation and interpretation processes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
with open("inp.txt", "r") as inpt:
        print(len(inpt.readlines()))
```